# Regarding になっている

Tags: て-form

A game I've been playing has released a new character and I've come across a reaction video in JP.

> 新キャラの役割はダメージになっている

I do understand the meaning of the sentence, except the「になっている」part. The way I've come to think of it over the years is that it denotes a state of being that has either been altered or decided by someone or something.

Please help me understand this point properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal translation is:

> The role（役割） of the new character（新キャラ） is damage(DPS, Damage Dealer, whatever you want to call it).

The original text itself seems to be missing a few necessary words (but the meaning is conveyed, so I guess it's for Japanese speakers).

I think it would be easier to understand if that sentence was written as:

> "新キャラの役目は、ダメージを出すという事を主としている - *The role of the new character is primarily to deal damage.*"

---

**Edit:**

As for 「になっている」 part.

The word "になっている" means that there is a rule, habit, or schedule/plan that dictates what you/someone/something will or will not do.　So yes, I think it's safe to say that you're on the right track.

In this case, the word "になっている" was used because it is *planned* that a new character will be implemented with the role of dealing damage.